# How to use max_id for pagination in Twitter API results (PHP)

Tags: php, twitter, pagination

I would like to use th Twitter API to get the statuses (and the related info) of users, one of the things I would like to get is mentions, so I search for to:"user" in the search API. I use these lines:

```
$url  = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=to%3A'.$screenname.'&include_entities=true&result_type=recent';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$searchStats = json_decode($json, true);
```

And in the resulting page (e.g. for Lady Gaga: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=to%3Aladygaga&include_entities=true&result_type=recent ) there is a line that says next_page, how can I automatically go to next page each time? How can I say to go to next page for e.g. as long as the resulting tweets are from after October 27, 2012?

I am first doing this in PHP, because that is the language I am learning, but I would eventually like to get this to be a client-side operation, with Jquery/Ajax once I learn some Ajax/Javascript (like:  http://designwithpc.com/post/11924263674/get-twitter-profile-data-with-jquery-ajax ), will that be possible? Is it translatable to that?

Comment: You might want to use the API instead: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets - It works with PHP but also has `callback` JSONP parameter so you can use via Javascript/AJAX.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely makes a lot more sense.